# Getting two users from seeds.rb file when I only want one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory-bot, seed

If this is the only line I have creating a user in my seeds.rb file:

jim = Factory :user, :name => "Jim Jones", :email => 'jim@test.com'

How come I end up with two users, one named Jim, and one with a random name as if it was just generated by the factory?

Thanks!

John

UPDATE:  The reason, I realize now, is because another factory is being created which has an association to user, and I don't specify which user, and so it would seem the factory with an association to user is generating a user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you defined `Factory :user` somewhere? That's the general use case for Factory anyways. With that defined calling `Factory :user` will return whatever it was defined to do before. Have a look at the [Getting Started With Factory_Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) page.

You should be able to call `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` from there.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I do define Factory :user in my factories.rb file.  Any idea why my syntax generates two?

Comment: I believe the issue is that you're using the method wrong. With the `FactoryGirl.create` method you can specify any attributes you want for the model. Not sure why you're getting returned an extra user though.